# Errors in middleware of NestJS

Tags: nestjs

I send requests from time to time. When an error occurs in the middleware, it is passed to the console. But then the client can not connect to the server and send any request. Connection is refused.
Error is not handled in the middleware because I rely on an attached exception filter.
The application exception filter isn't able to catch these errors. Can anyone confirm this behavior and provide advice on how to handle it? It appears that the middleware error handling documentation is currently missing.
https://docs.nestjs.com/middleware

```js
@Injectable()
export class FirebaseMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  constructor(private readonly firebaseService: FirebaseService) {}

  use(request: Request, _, next: NextFunction) {
    this.modify(request)
      .then(next);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation linked in your question explains:

> Nest middleware are, by default, equivalent to express middleware.

So you really need to consult the Express documentaion for more details on error handling.

See:

- https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html
- https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html
- https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

It's hard to say what you mean by "encountering errors with an injectable middleware that seems to be breaking my server" so it's impossible to tell you anything more specific, but hopefully you'll find the answer to your problem in the docs that describe the actual middleware used by Nest.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it really is because ExpressJS behavior and NestJS wrapper. In my case catch of the promise is absent. The easiest and most workable solution is to use async/await variant. It has not been described in the documentation. I do not know the exact behavior but it works correctly.

```js
@Injectable()
export class FirebaseMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  constructor(private readonly firebaseService: FirebaseService) {}

  async use(request: Request, _, next: NextFunction) {
    await this.modify(request);
    next();
  }
```

Some errors occur in the `modify` method. All errors are caught by the global exception filter and the server continue to receive requests.